# No overload matches this call Error with useReducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
`import React, {
  JSX,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useReducer,
  useEffect,
} from "react";
import reducer from "./Reducer";
import { actions } from "./Action";
import cartItems from "../data";

//React Element
interface ReactEl {
  children: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element;
}
interface ContextState {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  price: string;
  img: string;
  amount: number;
}

export interface IContext {
  loading: boolean;
  cart: Map<
    string,
    {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      price: string;
      img: string;
      amount: number;
    }
  >;
  clearCart: () => void;
}

const AppContext = createContext({} as IContext);

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  cart: new Map<
    string,
    {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      price: string;
      img: string;
      amount: number;
    }
  >(cartItems.map((item) => [item.id, { ...item }])),
};

const AppProvider = ({ children }: ReactEl) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  function clearCart() {
    dispatch({ type: actions.clear });
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ ...state, clearCart }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

//Use Global Hook
export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

export default AppProvider;
```

Actions and Reducer File
**Action and Reducer File**

```
 export enum actions {
      clear = "CLEAR_CART",
      increase = "INCREASE",
      decrease = "DECREASE",
      remove = "REMOVE",
      loading = "LOADING",
      display_items = "DISPLAY_ITEMS",
    }
    
    import { actions } from "./Action";
    import { IContext } from "./Context";
    //interface
    interface actionType {
      type: actions;
    }
    const reducer = (state: IContext, action: actionType) => {
      if (action.type === actions.clear) {
        return { ...state, cart: new Map() };
      }
      throw new Error(`No matching type found: ${action.type}`);
    };
    
    export default reducer;
```

I am constantly getting an error highlighted at the part below highlighted and the error states No overload matches this call. I am not able to understand tried a lot but nothing worked.
Secondly, how do I know what this kind of error states as it took my quite some time but still nothing worked. Is it because of the **IntitialState **that I decalred

```
`  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  function clearCart() {
    dispatch({ type: actions.clear });
  }`
```

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Hi Paulo, I hope this link helps
 https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-cdn-s4vkrj?file=/src/reducer.tsx

Comment: You have a few issues in your sandbox, first you have to fix the initial state, it is missing two properties clearCart and removeItem.   If you intend use them, then you'll have to initialize them in the initial state. but by looking at your code it soesn't seem like you need those functions in the reducer state. Fix that and you'll see that all the errors will dissapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `IContext`. You defined that one as follows

```
export interface IContext {
  loading: boolean;
  cart: Map<
    string,
    {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      price: string;
      img: string;
      amount: number;
    }
  >;
  clearCart: () => void;
}
```

But your `initialState` is missing `clearCart`. You could add a default noop function.

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  cart: new Map<
    string,
    {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      price: string;
      img: string;
      amount: number;
    }
  >(cartItems.map((item) => [item.id, { ...item }])),
  clearCart: () => {},
};
```

Comment: Thankyou @Federico and all of you guys for helping me out